# oracle query - additional where condition depending on a field

Tags: sql, oracle

Its hard to explain what exactly i mean using words so ill write a query similar to what i have at the moment.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.something = 'something' 
  AND CASE WHEN t.name = 'john' THEN 'smith' ELSE t.lastname END = t.lastname
```

Basicly depending if a field is what i want it to be (name = john) i want to add another condition (lastname = smith). If that field isnt what i want it to be (name != john) then no condition is needed (lastname can be whatever)
This code works but for me it seems to be kind of a hack. My question is if this can be done more easily or more prettily? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without the `case`:

```
WHERE t.something = 'something' AND
      (t.lastname = 'smith' or t.name <> 'john')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the entire test within the `CASE` statement:

```
AND CASE WHEN t.name = 'john' THEN t.lastname = 'smith' ELSE True
```

(I don't remember my Oracle so well.  `True` may not be the correct term here.)

Now the result of the `CASE` is a truth value rather than a value to be tested against `t.lastname`.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to:

```
WHERE
  t.name = 'john' AND t.lastname = 'smith' 
  OR t.name <> 'john'
```